# AST transformation in CLASS_GENERATION phase

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree, dsl

I'm working on a custom AST transformation that needs a static type data. Basically want i want to do is to add an assignment expression that takes the closure inferred return type and set it to some field:

```
valueGetter = { Foo f -> f.someString }
// I want the below to be added via AST transformation
type = String.class
```

I'm getting a closure return type using:

```
(ClassNode) exp.getNodeMetaData(StaticTypesMarker.INFERRED_RETURN_TYPE)
```

But the problem is that it's populated with return type during INSTRUCTION_SELECTION phase. Therefore I'm applying my AST during next phase which is CLASS_GENERATION. I'm adding the ExpressionStatement but it doesn't seem to work. If I change the CompilePhase to SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS the assignment expression works but I don't have StaticTypesMarker.INFERRED_RETURN_TYPE populated for closure.

The questions are:

1. I would like to know if it is possible to add expression statements to the AST during CLASS_GENERATION phase? I doesn't seem to work for me. Documentation is not clear here:

> Global transformations may be applied in any phase, but local
>   transformations may only be applied in the semantic analysis phase or
>   later.

2. If it is not possible to modify AST during CLASS_GENERATION  then is it legal to use StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitClosure to get closure inferred return type during SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS phase?
3. Are there any other options I might have missed?